# C# Serilog What is causing this convert type error?

Tags: c#, serilog

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting this error and would like some help:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Serilog.Core.Logger' to 'Serilog.LoggerConfiguration'

Mind you I'm not at all an expert at C# and haven't written any in a long while.  This is me 'Attempting' to write a logger for a game engine I want to try writing in my free time.

I've installed both Serilog and Serlog.Sinks.Console thru the NuGet manager in Visual Studio

I'm basing my code off the libraries getting started guide: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Getting-Started

My code

```
using Serilog;
using System;

namespace FFEngine.src
{
    public sealed class Log
    {
        static Log()
        {
            _coreLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .CreateLogger();
        }

        private Log()
        {
        }

        ~Log()
        {
           
        }

        public static Log Instance { get { return _instance; } }

        private static readonly Log _instance = new Log();
        private static LoggerConfiguration _coreLogger;
        private static LoggerConfiguration _clientLogger;
    }
}
```

Comment: Small aside: definitely remove the `~Log` - this should never have made it into the C# language ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new LoggerConfiguration().CreateLogger` creates an instance of `Serilog.Core.Logger`, not `Serilog.LoggerConfiguration`

You should declare your field as `private static Logger _coreLogger;`

Comment: Yep that did it. Seams so obvious in hindsight. I was focusing on the line that showed the error though. Thanks.